# The value or constructor is not defined

Tags: f#

I have defined both records and created a union from them, but F# still complains that the constructor "Food" is not defined. What is the problem?

```
type Product = {Name : string; BasePrice: int}
type Size = {Medium: int; Large: int}

type Food = | Product of Product| Size of Size

let food = Food({Name = "Bagel"; BasePrice = 20}; {Medium = 10; Large = 20})
```

Comment: `Food` is a type not a constructor, you need something like `let food = Product {Name = "Bagel"; BasePrice = 20}`. Are you trying to build a `list Food`?

Comment: @Lee I think you have the correct answer. Pls, add it as an answer to this question. This way Denki can mark it as the correct answer and this will add to your reputation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Food` is a type, not a constructor - to create a value of type `Food` you need to use one of the constructors `Product` or `Size`. It looks like you're trying to construct a `list Food`, in which case you can use:

```
let food = [Product {Name = "Bagel"; BasePrice = 20}; Size {Medium = 10; Large = 20}]
```